# convert dataframe into 2-mode network matrix, this is an example , its my first time i use R

Tags: r

```
1   Sam     a
2   Sam     b
3   Sam     c
4  Greg     a
5   Tom     b
6   Tom     c
7   Tom     d
8  Mary     b
9  Mary     d
```

Two-Mode Adjacency Matrix that I want to have :
I tried as.matrix, frame2web but

```
     a b c d
Sam  1 1 1 0
Greg 1 0 0 0
Tom  0 1 1 1
Mary 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: `table(df)` where `df` is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table(df)` to create the two-mode adjacency matrix

```
tb <- table(df)
> tb
      value
name   a b c d
  Greg 1 0 0 0
  Mary 0 1 0 1
  Sam  1 1 1 0
  Tom  0 1 1 1
```

If you want to keep the order of names according to the sequence of names appearing in `df`, then you can also use `order()` to reorder the rows in ``tb`, i.e.,

```
> tb[order(match(rownames(tb),df$name)),]
      value
name   a b c d
  Sam  1 1 1 0
  Greg 1 0 0 0
  Tom  0 1 1 1
  Mary 0 1 0 1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Greg", "Mary", "Sam", "Tom"), class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")
```